# SQL Duplicated names in result

Tags: sql

I've got problem with SQL.
Here is my code:

```
SELECT Miss.Name, Miss.Surname, Master.Name, Master.Surname,
            COUNT(Date.Id_date) AS [Dates_together]
FROM Miss, Master, Date
WHERE Date.Id_miss = Miss.Id_miss AND Date.Id_master = Master.Id_master
GROUP BY Miss.Name, Miss.Surname, Master.Name, Master.Surname
ORDER BY [Dates_together] DESC
```

and I've got the result:

```
Dorothy | Mills   | James | Jackson | 28
Dorothy | Mills   | Kayne | West    | 28
Emily   | Walters | James | Jackson | 13
Emily   | Walters | Tom   | Marvel  | 12
Sunny   | Sunday  | Kayne | West    | 9
```

and I really do not know what to change to have a result like this:

```
Dorothy | Mills   | James | Jackson | 28
Emily   | Walters | Tom   | Marvel  | 12
Sunny   | Sunday  | Kayne | West    | 9
```

Because I don't want to to have duplicated names of master or miss in a result... :(
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server? MySQL?  Oracle?  Informix?  DB/2?  Sybase?  PostGres?  Ingres?  PervasiveSQL? Btrieve?  Ashton-Tate DBase III+?

Comment: Can you post your table structures, and crucially what the relations are between them?

Comment: You haven't stated your actual goal in a clear way.
Given - for example - that Emily Walters was on 13 dates with James and 12 with Tom, what is the rule that decides that you want to show the row about Tom? 

Please restate the problem, for example saying "In case of more than a result for a given lady, I only want the row satisfying ..." and than state what the criteria are.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your result set is correct, as you are getting the appropriate distinct combinations.

Answer (score 0):

The "duplicates" are accurate, because you are querying the combinations of the Miss and Master records, not the Miss and Master records themselves.  For instance, in your second result set, it doesn't capture the fact that Dorothy Mills dated Kayne West 28 times.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which database you're working with, but if I have this correctly you're trying to determine how many times a given couple have been on a date?

I think you need to ask your self what happens if you have two people, of either sex, that share the same combination of christian and surname...

Start off with :

Select idMaster, idMiss, count(*) as datecount from [Date] group by idMaster, idDate

From there, you need to simply need to add their names to the results...

Should get you started on the right track...